# Cross-browser innerText for setting values

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, innertext

Let's say I have the following code:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
   <div id="d">some text</div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var d = document.getElementByid('d');
    var innerText = d.innerText || d.textContent;

    innerText = 'new text';
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And I want to change text value for the div tag with id='d'. Unfortunately the block code above doesn't work and the text content doesn't change.

It works if do the following recipe:

```
if (d.innerText) d.innerText = 'new text';
else d.textContent = 'new text';
```

But I dont like the recipe above because it's not compact.

Have you any suggestions why the first approach doesn't work?

Comment: Why don't you put the second solution into a function with a parameter for the element and one for the string. Then you'd just have to do `setText(mydiv, "new text");`

Comment: it is not `document.getElementByid` it should be `document.getElementById` `I` of `id` should be in capital.

Comment: `d[('innerText' in d) ? 'innerText' : 'textContent' ] = 'New text';`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Instead of multiple assignments, you can grab the property and use that

```
var text = ('innerText' in d)? 'innerText' : 'textContent';
d[text] = 'New text';
```

Comment: This is a brilliant way of handling it, glad I stumbled across it.

Answer (score 8):

The first approach doesn't work because all it does is set the variable to the new value, it doesn't write the value to the element. The line

```
var innerText = d.innerText || d.textContent;
```

...sets the variable `innerText` to the *value* of the text property it finds, it's not a reference to the actual property itself.

You'll have to do the branch, e.g.:

```
var d = document.getElementById('d');
var msg = "new text";
if ("innerText" in d) {
    d.innerText = msg;
}
else {
    d.textContent = msg;
}
```

That feature-detects whether the browser uses `innerText` or `textContent` by looking for the existence of the property on the element (that's what the `in` operator does, check if an object has a property with the given name, even if that property is blank, `null`, `undefined`, etc.).

You can even write yourself a function for it:

```
var setText = (function() {
    function setTextInnerText(element, msg) {
        element.innerText = msg;
    }

    function setTextTextContent(element, msg) {
        element.textContent = msg;
    }

    return "innerText" in document.createElement('span') ? setTextInnerText : setTextTextContent;
})();
```

That does the feature-detection once, and returns a function any half-decent engine will inline for you.

Or alternately, if you want HTML markup in the message to be handled as markup (rather than literal text), you can just use `innerHTML` (which is consistent across browsers). But again, if you use `innerHTML`, markup will be processed which may not be what you want.

---

I find it useful to use a good JavaScript library to deal with these browser differences (and to provide a *ton* of useful further functionality), such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). Obviously there's nothing you can do with a library you can't do without one, it's just a matter of standing on the shoulders of people who've done a huge amount of work already. :-)

In this case, for instance, using jQuery the above would be:

```
$("#d").text("new text");
```

That's it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I need innerText. Ok I'll use the branch

Comment: Does YUI has a method innerText?

Comment: @Erik: Glad that helped. I explained how it works (the feature test) a bit more.

Comment: @Erik: *"Does YUI has a method innerText"* A cursory search of the documentation suggests [that yes, it does](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/DOM.html#method_setText). (I don't use YUI, but the docs are pretty easy to use.)

Comment: your code will not work because it has a typo `getElementByid` should be `getElementById`

Comment: @A.K: Well, it's a typo I inherited from the OP's code. :-) Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
d.appendChild(document.createTextNode("new text");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `textContent` only & it will work in major browsers... (FF, Safari & Chrome)

```
var d = document.getElementById('d');
var msg = "new text";
d.textContent = msg;
```