# Can this time script be updated automatically?

Tags: javascript, time

I am using the following script for showing the current time on my website:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

    var currentTime = new Date()
    var hours = currentTime.getHours()
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
    if (minutes < 10)
        minutes = "0" + minutes
    var suffix = "AM";
    if (hours >= 12) {
        suffix = "PM";
        hours = hours - 12;
    }
    if (hours == 0) {
        hours = 12;
    }

    document.write("<b>" + hours + ":" + minutes + " " + suffix + "</b>")
//-->
</script>
```

However, I need to refresh the page in order for the time to update. Can I have the time refresh every minute automatically so it stays up to date?

Thanks.

Comment: I recommend you look at using [Livestamp.js](http://mattbradley.github.io/livestampjs/)

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping if possible to use the existing code already in place.I was looking at a function like setInterval but it requires my existing script to be wrapped in a function. I tried that and it broke. Perhaps I am doing it wrong?

Comment: I don't see a point in rolling your own.. years ago you had to but use a library if its available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setInterval to have that code execute every x milliseconds:

```
function setTime() {
    var currentTime = new Date()
    var hours = currentTime.getHours()
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
    if (minutes < 10)
        minutes = "0" + minutes
    var suffix = "AM";
    if (hours >= 12) {
        suffix = "PM";
        hours = hours - 12;
    }
    if (hours == 0) {
        hours = 12;
    }

    document.write("<b>" + hours + ":" + minutes + " " + suffix + "</b>")
}

setInterval(setTime, 60000);
```

Note, it is generally a bad practice to use `document.write`. A better approach would be to have the displayed element statically on the page, and update it in the method.

```
document.getElementById('currentTime').innerText = hours + ":" + minutes + " " + suffix;
```

Here is a working [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3n5zf/)

Comment: Thanks very much! This works well in Chrome, but the time disappears in Firefox for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `textContent` instead of `innerText`. I believe this is more cross-browser compatible. Check out [This Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646398/cross-browser-innertext-for-setting-values) for making something that will work in multiple browsers.

Comment: It works great in Firefox now, but on Android with the default browser I'm still not getting anything. Is there something different required for that?

Comment: Apparently, Android browser supports `innerHTML`. I don't do a lot mobile web development, so I am not sure what the approach to take for that would be.