# insert no-break space by element.innerText

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, innerhtml, innertext

In a web application I dynamically create a large and quite complex table with about [10,000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26653729/insert-no-break-space-by-element-innertext/26653839#comment41910999_26653839) empty cells in a first step (some table cells will stay empty, some not). My first appoach used innerHtml with a [no-break space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/index.htm) to prevent empty cells from collapsing:

```js
td.innerHtml = '&nbsp;';
```

But that was rather slow. Then I [discovered](http://jsperf.com/createtextnode-vs-textcontent-vs-innerhtml-vs-innertext) that to set innerText is much faster than setting innerHtml. So I changed my code to

```js
td.innerText = '\u00a0';
```

because `td.innerText = '&nbsp;'` just wrote the text `"&nbsp;"` in each cell. It seemed to work in Internet Explorer 11 but in Firefox the borders of the empty cells disappeared. But I do not see any difference if I inspect the cells (via Firebug or something) and compare them with my previous version.

Comment: Firefox does not support `innerText`, in favour of `textContent`

Comment: `innerText` is Microsoft's proprietary extensions, iirc.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what "collapsing" means, nor why this can't be solved *much* more efficiently with CSS.

Comment: **Do not fix this with JS**. Use `empty-cells: show;` in your CSS.

Comment: empty-cells didn't work for me :o

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`element.innerText` is not a standard property. It was introduced by Microsoft into Internet Explorer, but no other browsers are guaranteed to support it (which is why you're seeing quirks).

Use `element.textContent` or rethink your approach. Generating a 10k *empty* cells table sounds like a very bad idea.

Comment: Chrome very well supports `innerText`. Just like it supports `document.all`...

Comment: I never said that no other browser supports it, I said that no one **guarantees** support, because it's not standard.

Comment: In most cases there are much less cells. 10k is a more exceptional case but it sometimes happens. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: As old IE (e.g. IE9) have problems with textContent I had to use both methods. For cross-browser text setting see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646398/cross-browser-innertext-for-setting-values

Comment: If you need multiple browser support, use jQuery.

Comment: Nowadays innerText is widely support across all browsers. See https://caniuse.com/innertext

Comment: My answer stands, stick to standards, avoid quirks. It's worth noting that back in '14, innerText was not a standard property, it was added to the standard much later to maintain compatibility.