# Why it is not printing the character in a paragraph?

Tags: javascript

Write a script that inputs an integer code for a character and displays the corresponding character.

It should print in a paragraph.

```js
function character() {
    var input = document.getElementById( "input" );
    var code = document.getElementById( "output" ).innerHTML = input;
    output.value = String.fromCharCode( code );
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" size="10">
<br>
<input type="button" value="click here" onclick="character()" id="button">
<br>
<p id="output" ></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `P` is not a form element. Also if you use form.fieldName, you need to use `name=""` instead of `id=""`; otherwise use `document.getElementById` for all fields and ignore the form.

You need to use innerHTML or [innerText/textContent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646398/cross-browser-innertext-for-setting-values) for a paragraph

```
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=...
```

```js
function character() {
  var form = document.getElementById("form");
  var code = parseInt(form.input.value,10); // radix 10 to make decimal
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = String.fromCharCode(code);
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input name="input" type="text" size="10">
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="click here" onclick="character()" id="button">
  <br>
  <p id="output" ></p>
</form>
```

Comment: i must make it in p@mplungjan

Comment: See update with additional fixes - I may have given you too much information for a homework assignment

Comment: That is the [radix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix). It is needed to handle  people inputting something beginning with 0x where x is < 9 since that is considered [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal)

Comment: it gives me this Vote Up requires 15 reputation @mplungjan

Comment: Yes. My favourite. I read the first and second edition to pieces [JavaScript, the Definitive Guide](http://amzn.to/1SLwAkp) - now in 6th edition.

Answer (score 1):

You have the problem for access to the elements inside a form.

```
document.getElementById("form").elements['input']
```

But this only works with form elements, not with other HTML elements.

In this of elements, you can use **id** or **name** but for historical reasons.

You have another way here:

```js
function character() {
  var input = document.getElementById("input"),
      output = document.getElementById("output");
      output.innerHTML = String.fromCharCode(parseInt(input.value), 10) || '';
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input id="input" type="text" size="10">
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="click here" onclick="character()" id="button">
  <br>
  <p id="output" ></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, this works:

```
<script>
function character() {
var ChrCode = document.getElementById("input").value;
document.getElementById("output").innerText = ChrCode + " = " + String.fromCharCode(ChrCode);
//output.value = String.fromCharCode( code );
}
</script>

<input id="input" type="text" size="10">
<br>
<input type="button" value="click here" onclick="character()" id="button">
<br>
<p id="output" >Output</p>
```