# Input type button does not call the onclick function inline

Tags: javascript, html

I was making a calculator for a game and made a button like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Calculate" name="Calc_Button" onclick="cpbCalc()" class="button_is">
```

When button is clicked, I want to run the `cpbCalc()` function.
You can find this html code live on http://trial.6te.net/Calculators/cpbCalculatorNew.html

Here is the complete html Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Cost Per Battle Calculator
    </title>
</head>

<style>
.smaller{
    width: 50px;
    padding: 12px 10px;
    margin: 0px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.bigger{
    width: 110px;
    padding: 12px 10px;
    margin: 0px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.button_is{
    width: 110px;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 0px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button_is:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}

div {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #badf6f;
    padding:20px;
}
</style>

<body>
<div>
    <!-- <label for="fname" id="fn">First Name</label> -->
    <!-- <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname"> -->
    <!-- <button onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button> -->
     <table border="0">
        <tr>
             <td>
                <center><img src="http://trial.6te.net/images/gold.gif"></img></center>
            </td>
            <td>
                <center><img src="http://trial.6te.net/images/wood_s.gif"></img></center>
            </td>
            <td>
                <center><img src="http://trial.6te.net/images/ore_s.gif"></img></center>
            </td>
            <td>
                <center><img src="http://trial.6te.net/images/mercury_s.gif"></img></center>
            </td>
            <td>
                <center><img src="http://trial.6te.net/images/sulphur_S.gif"></img></center>
            </td>
            <td>
                <center><img src="http://trial.6te.net/images/crystal_S.gif"></img></center>
            </td>
            <td>
                <center><img src="http://trial.6te.net/images/gems_S.gif"></img></center>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="gold_" name="Gold" class="bigger">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="wood_" name="Wood" class="smaller" value="0">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="ore_" name="Ore" class="smaller" value="0">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="mercury_" name="Mercury" class="smaller" value="0">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="sulphur_" name="Sulphur" class="smaller" value="0">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="crystals_" name="Crystals" class="smaller" value="0">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="gems_" name="Gems" class="smaller" value="0">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Durability :<br>
                <input type="text" id="currDura_" name="Current_Durability" class="smaller">  /
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="maxDura_" name="Maximum_Durability" class="smaller">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Repair Cost :<br>
                <input type="text" id="repCost_" name="Repair_Cost" class="bigger">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Smith Efficiency :<br>
                <input type="text" id="smithEffi_" name="Smith_Efficiency" class="smaller">
            </td>
            <td>
                Smith Charges :<br>
                <input type="text" id="smithCharge_" name="Smith_Charge" class="smaller">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="7">
                <center><input type="button" value="Calculate" name="Calc_Button" onclick="cpbCalc()" class="button_is"></center> 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="7">
                <label id="result_"></label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<script language="JavaScript">
<!-- 
function cpbCalc() {
    var currDura, maxDura, tempMaxDura, tempDura, totDura, optDura;
    var iniCost, repCost;
    var smithEffi, smithCharge;
    var se, sc;
    var totCostTillNow, costPerBattle = 0, minCPB;
    var i;
    var repCount = 1;
    //Assigning the values
    currDura = document.getElementById("currDura_").value;
    maxDura = document.getElementById("maxDura_").value;
    iniCost = document.getElementById("gold_").value;
    repCost = document.getElementById("repCost_").value;
    smithEffi = document.getElementById("smithEffi_").value;
    smithCharge = document.getElementById("smithCharge_").value;

    se = smithEffi / 100;
    sc = smithCharge / 100;
    tempMaxDura = maxDura;
    tempDura = currDura;
    totDura = tempDura;
    totCostTillNow = parseFloat(iniCost);
    costPerBattle = parseFloat(totCostTillNow / totDura);
    minCPB = parseFloat(costPerBattle);
    optDura = parseInt(tempMaxDura);

    for(i=1; i<=maxDura; i++)
    {
        totCostTillNow += parseFloat(repCost * sc);
        tempDura = parseInt(tempMaxDura * se);
        totDura += parseInt(tempDura);
        costPerBattle = parseFloat(totCostTillNow / totDura);
        tempMaxDura -= 1;
        if ( minCPB >=  costPerBattle )
        {
            minCPB = parseFloat(costPerBattle);
            optDura = parseInt(tempMaxDura);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("result_").value = eval(minCPB) + " gold at 0/"+ eval(optDura);
    return 0;
    //alert("minimum cost per battle = " + eval(minCPB) + "at 0/" + eval(optDura));
//-->
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here "result_" is a label where I want to provide the final answer.
When I click the button, it should run the function "`cpbCalc()`" but it doesn't.

Instead it does nothing.
 Also when I check in Console, it shows no errors.
Can you help me why this is occurring and provide a solution for it?

Comment: Why do you have an html comment inside of your script block? Using eval is a bad idea. `<center>` is a Deprecated tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some typos in your script:

- never use eval: it's a threat and mainly you do not need it
- to convert text values to numbers a way is to add the + in front of value
  like +document.getElementById("currDura_").value
- avoid division by zero like  for totDura. A way can be: (totDura == 0) ? 1 : totDura)
- use [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) instead of value property to change the label text

The snippet:

```js
function cpbCalc() {
  var currDura, maxDura, tempMaxDura, tempDura, totDura, optDura;
  var iniCost, repCost;
  var smithEffi, smithCharge;
  var se, sc;
  var totCostTillNow, costPerBattle = 0, minCPB;
  var i;
  var repCount = 1;
  //Assigning the values
  currDura = +document.getElementById("currDura_").value;
  maxDura = +document.getElementById("maxDura_").value;
  iniCost = +document.getElementById("gold_").value;
  repCost = +document.getElementById("repCost_").value;
  smithEffi = +document.getElementById("smithEffi_").value;
  smithCharge = +document.getElementById("smithCharge_").value;

  se = smithEffi / 100;
  sc = smithCharge / 100;
  tempMaxDura = maxDura;
  tempDura = currDura;
  totDura = tempDura;
  totCostTillNow = parseFloat(iniCost);
  costPerBattle = parseFloat(totCostTillNow / (totDura == 0) ? 1 : totDura); // avoid division by zero
  minCPB = parseFloat(costPerBattle);
  optDura = parseInt(tempMaxDura);

  for(i=1; i<=maxDura; i++)
  {
    totCostTillNow += parseFloat(repCost * sc);
    tempDura = parseInt(tempMaxDura * se);
    totDura += parseInt(tempDura);
    costPerBattle = parseFloat(totCostTillNow / totDura);
    tempMaxDura -= 1;
    if ( minCPB >=  costPerBattle )
    {
      minCPB = parseFloat(costPerBattle);
      optDura = parseInt(tempMaxDura);
    }
  }

  // For labels use textContent instead of value property
  document.getElementById("result_").textContent = minCPB + " gold at 0/"+ optDura; // never use eval
  return 0;
  //alert("minimum cost per battle = " + eval(minCPB) + "at 0/" + eval(optDura));
  //-->
}
```

```css
.smaller{
  width: 50px;
  padding: 12px 10px;
  margin: 0px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.bigger{
  width: 110px;
  padding: 12px 10px;
  margin: 0px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.button_is{
  width: 110px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 0px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button_is:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
}

div {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #badf6f;
  padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <!-- <label for="fname" id="fn">First Name</label> -->
    <!-- <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname"> -->
    <!-- <button onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button> -->
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <center><img src="http://trial.6te.net/images/gold.gif"></img></center>
            </td>
            <td>
                <center><img src="http://trial.6te.net/images/wood_s.gif"></img></center>
            </td>
            <td>
                <center><img src="http://trial.6te.net/images/ore_s.gif"></img></center>
            </td>
            <td>
                <center><img src="http://trial.6te.net/images/mercury_s.gif"></img></center>
            </td>
            <td>
                <center><img src="http://trial.6te.net/images/sulphur_S.gif"></img></center>
            </td>
            <td>
                <center><img src="http://trial.6te.net/images/crystal_S.gif"></img></center>
            </td>
            <td>
                <center><img src="http://trial.6te.net/images/gems_S.gif"></img></center>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="gold_" name="Gold" class="bigger">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="wood_" name="Wood" class="smaller" value="0">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="ore_" name="Ore" class="smaller" value="0">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="mercury_" name="Mercury" class="smaller" value="0">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="sulphur_" name="Sulphur" class="smaller" value="0">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="crystals_" name="Crystals" class="smaller" value="0">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="gems_" name="Gems" class="smaller" value="0">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Durability :<br>
                <input type="text" id="currDura_" name="Current_Durability" class="smaller">  /
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="maxDura_" name="Maximum_Durability" class="smaller">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Repair Cost :<br>
                <input type="text" id="repCost_" name="Repair_Cost" class="bigger">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Smith Efficiency :<br>
                <input type="text" id="smithEffi_" name="Smith_Efficiency" class="smaller">
            </td>
            <td>
                Smith Charges :<br>
                <input type="text" id="smithCharge_" name="Smith_Charge" class="smaller">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="7">
                <center><input type="button" value="Calculate" name="Calc_Button" onclick="cpbCalc()" class="button_is"></center>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="7">
                <label id="result_"></label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace :

```
document.getElementById("result_").value = eval(minCPB) + " gold at 0/"+ eval(optDura);
```

With :

```
document.getElementById("result_").innerHTML = eval(minCPB) + " gold at 0/"+ eval(optDura);
```

The  tag does't have a "value" attribut. It's why it's not working but you don't have errors.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

If the value will be retruned or not

Answer (score 0):

The debugger is your friend.

A couple things:

First, when you read a value from an input box that you want to use as a number in your script, you need to convert it to a number. For example:

```
currDura = document.getElementById("currDura_").value;
```

should be:

```
currDura = parseInt(document.getElementById("currDura_").value);
```

In production code this also needs to perform error checking (users may enter non-numeric values), but this is fine for testing.

I see that you are parsing some of the values later on in the code, but you're also using some of them before converting to numbers (e.g., `se = smithEffi / 100').

Second, you really should avoid using `eval`. If you have converted the input values to numbers, this should not be necessary.

Finally, `value` is not the correct property of the label. My recommendation is to use jQuery and assign the content like so:

```
$('#result_').text('text to show in label');
```

You can use the `innerHTML` property, but I typically don't recommend this because you may need to deal with encoding the text.

You can assign text using pure JavaScript, but it's a bit more involved due to potential cross-browser issues. See [Cross-browser innerText for setting values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646398/cross-browser-innertext-for-setting-values) for some examples of how to do this.